# Is the StackExchange API free of charge?

Tags: support, api

I am brand new to StackApps, so please bear with me for a question that is hopefully obvious to most regular users.

As far as I can tell, there is no charge for accessing the StackExchange API. Apparently, even registration that brings increased usage permissions does not incur any charge.

I would like to know this for sure, but surprisingly, despite searching for quite a while, I cannot find any documentation anywhere that definitely says that the StackExchange API is free of charge. In particular, I would expect something mentioned in the [API documentation](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) or in the [terms of use](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/api-terms-of-use), or even in a [prior question to StackApps](https://stackapps.com/search?q=pricing%20api), but I can find nothing anywhere.

So, could someone please tell me definitely: **is there any fee to use StackExchange API or is it completely free of charge?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is completely and unconditionally free. (Although there are usage limits, which are described [here](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/throttle).)

It is not even necessary to create an account in order to use it. (Although an account is required to perform certain privileged operations. However, you can use the API to retrieve essentially anything that an anonymous user browsing the Stack Exchange public website could see.)